# readline() не читает первую строку (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно написать программу, которая считывает текст из файла (в файле может быть больше одной строки) и выводит самое частое слово в этом тексте и через пробел то, сколько раз оно встретилось. При решении этой задачи столкнулся с проблемой. Я читаю файл построчно с помощью readline(), но почему-то первая строка не считывается. Если в файле одна строка, то программа выводит пустой словарь. Если более, то выводит словарь с данными, но пропускает первую строку. Почему?

```
data = {}
with open("input.txt") as f1:
    for line in f1:
        line = f1.readline().lower().split()
        set_line = set(line)
        for i in set_line:
            if i in line:
                 data[i] = line.count(i)
print(data)
```

Comment: Строку `line = f1.readline().lower().split()` замените на `line = line.lower().split()`

Comment: Ваш код пропускает каждую вторую строку начиная с нулевой, т.к. `for line in f1` - уже читает строку в переменную `line` и `f1.readline()` - читает следующую строку.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем коде сам цикл `for line in f1:` читает файл построчно. В цикле вы игнорируете строку, которую он дает, и самостоятельно читаете строку еще раз, ее значение уже используете. Получается, что вы игнорируете все нечетные строки (первую, третью, пятую и т.д.) Нужно избавиться от повторного чтения строки, вместо этого работать с той строкой, которую вам дает цикл:

```
data = {}
with open("input.txt") as f1:
    for line in f1:
        line = line.lower().split()
        set_line = set(line)
        for i in set_line:
            if i in line:
                 data[i] = line.count(i)
print(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте такой вариант, через read()

```
 with open("text.txt") as f:
        doc = f.read()


    words_dict= {}
    for i in doc.split('\n'):
        for j in i.split():
            words_dict[j] = words_dict.get(j,0) + 1

    lst = list(words_dict.items())

    lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda word: word[1], reverse=True)
    print(*lst[0])
```